# Promote geneaogy.se at family gatherings

Tags: discussion, publicity

We have a small family gathering today and a larger one next Sunday (Easter). My hope is to grab a few interested family members and have a 'mini genealogy.se party' during the larger gathering. I don't know if it will be a series of 1-on-1's or a group effort. My hope will be some new members and some new questions today and some more next Sunday.

Any suggestions? Have others done this?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Might be sensible to pick a few questions in advance to illustrate the value of the site?

Comment: How did it go?  Perhaps you can post your own answer to encourage others to try the same.

Comment: a couple nibbles. I sat down with 3 relatives at first gathering and they are now members. Too hectic at second gathering - I should have made the time but didn't get a chance